# How do I change the default settings in IntelliJ to open a file in the current tab

Tags: intellij-idea, user-experience

I find the UX of IntelliJ to be extremely annoying (especially since I have been using XCode until now and really love it). Specifically the fact that I need to "double click" a file in order to view it, and moreover that the file is opened in a new tab.

The behaviour that I desire is that when selecting a new file from the file navigator, the file open "inside" (replace) the currently viewed tab. I don't want to have to double-click the file from the navigator and I don't want the file to open in a new tab.

So for instance if the current tab is showing "File1.xxx" and I were to select (Single-click) "File2.xxx" from the navigator, the tab would now show "File2.xxx" and not "File1.xxx".

I am not aware of how to define this behaviour in the settings screen.

I am using `IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.2` on a Mac.

A couple of examples of what I want:

**Like in XCode:**
[image]

**Like in Chrome:**
[image]

**Like in Safari:**
[image]

**Like in Finder:**
[image]

Comment: I'm quite happy without tabs, maybe it helps in your case to just disable tabs?

Comment: No - I really love having tabs. I just find it extremely annoying that opening a file defines opening a new tab. It makes absolutely no sense UX wise. Imagine a case where every time you were to "drill down" into a folder inside the Finder a new tab would open. I find it absurd 

Comment: Replied [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000542104-Open-files-in-the-same-tab-that-is-currently-visible).

Comment: Thanks but doesn't solve the problem at hand

Comment: I thought I understood your question, until your comment about also wanting tabs. How would the ide know when you wanted a new tab rather than opening the selected file in the current tab? How do you get both? The single-double click thing is easy to achieve, btw. The tab thing -- if you can explain it a little better we may be able to offer a solution. Single tab is the normal route for this.

Comment: Exactly like XCode does it (or Chrome or Safari or Firefox or Finder...) Everything opens in the same tab that has the current context . Tabs are opened explicitly by the user when pressing the "+" add tab icon